$T$-matrix for unstable particle, and the sign of the imaginary part of $T$-matrix
In What is $i\epsilon$ for the $S$-matrix, sec 2.3 talks about $T$-matrix of the unstable particles, which is defined by considering 1PI diagram contributing to one-particle propagator, which is complex,
$$\mathbf{T}_{1\rightarrow1} = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0+}\frac{1}{p^2-\mathfrak{m}^2+i(m\Gamma+\epsilon)}\tag{2.13}$$
and the imaginary part of $T$-matrix would be
$$\text{Im}\,\mathbf{T}_{1\rightarrow1} = -\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0+}\frac{m\Gamma + \epsilon}{(p^2-\mathfrak{m}^2)^2 + (m\Gamma+\epsilon)^2}\tag{2.20}$$
for $\Gamma > 0$, but in the summary (2.21),
$$\text{Im}\,\mathbf{T}_{1\rightarrow1} = \text{Im}\left[\frac{1}{(p^2-\mathfrak{m}^2) \color{red}{-} im\Gamma}\right]\tag{2.21}$$
which is different, and I think the correct one should be,
$$\text{Im}\,\mathbf{T}_{1\rightarrow1} = \text{Im}\left[\frac{1}{(p^2-\mathfrak{m}^2) \color{red}{+} im\Gamma}\right].$$

OP asks a valid question.

Usually the transfer matrix is [1]
$$ {\cal T}~=~(2\pi)^4\delta^4(\sum p){\cal M}, \tag{5.17}$$
where ${\cal M}$ is an amputated$^1$ Feynman diagram. The imaginary part ${\rm Im}{\cal T}\geq 0$ is non-negative, cf. the optical theorem (2.5).
But the self-energy-dressed propagator (2.12)/(2.13) is not an amputated Feynman diagram. And the corresponding imaginary part (2.20) is in fact non-positive.
In contrast, the apparently wrong sign in eq. (2.21) [that OP asks about] seems designed to make the imaginary part positive.

The fact [mentioned on top of p. 23] that the optical theorem (2.5) implies that ${\rm Im}\Sigma\geq 0$ is non-negative was deduced by looking at an amputated self-energy diagram [3].


References:

H.S. Hannesdottir & S. Mizera, What is $i\epsilon$ for the $S$-matrix?, arXiv:2204.02988; chapter 2. The Minkowski signature is mostly-minus.

M.D. Schwartz, QFT & the standard model, 2014; eq. (5.17).

M.D. Schwartz, QFT & the standard model, 2014; eq. (24.48).


--
$^1$ Note that e.g. eq. (2.24) corresponds to an amputated Feynman diagram.

Yeah, I totally agree with you!
